# Hide Part from UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, uicollectionview

So i have a UIView with blue background and a uicollectionview that have 3 cells in each row with the cells background colour set to blue and the UICollectionview background
set to black , imagine this scenario where i have 4 cells , the first 3 cells will fill the first row and the fourth cell will be the only cell in the second row and here comes the problem the rest of the second row will be black (the UICollectionview background ) what if i wanted the rest of the second row to have the same colour as the cell and the UIView background colour (blue) but in the same time i want to keep the background colour of the UICollectionview as it as in order to keep the cell separators black is there a way to hide the part of the UICollectionview that has no cells in it ??

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve your problem:

1. Mask the part of the collectionView which should be invisible
2. Fill the row up with empty cells which only have the backgroundcolor set
3. Remove the margins between all cells and create black borders in the cell prototype which act like separators.

I'd recommend the 3rd way :)